# Log4j 2: How to add references from my classes in my log4j.properties

Tags: java, log4j2

is my first question, sorry If I make a mistake asking my question.

Well this is my doubt about log4j2.(I use spring framework java)

My goal is write in a FILE all logs generated in classes wich have a Logger instance.

For this purpose I have the following log4j.properties file:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = C:/sts-bundle/Tomcat 7.0/logs
appenders = console,rolling

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c{5} - %msg%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}/fnelLog-${date:dd-MM-yyyy}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${filename}/fnelLog-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c{5} - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
#appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
#appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=50MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 4

loggers = rolling

 ############ HERE IS MY PROBLEM, I Only reference to this class, but I want to    add another, 
 ############ so I can write all logs in a file described in lines before
logger.rolling.name = fnel.bcp.org.main.TestMain
logger.rolling.level = debug
#logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile


rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

And Now here are the two clases which I used the Logger interface.

```
public class FooClass {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FooClass.class);

    public void testLog4j() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.debug("This is a debug message");
        logger.info("This is an info message");
        logger.warn("This is a warn message");
        logger.error("This is an error message");
        logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
    }

}



public class TestMain {

  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestMain.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FooClass foo = new FooClass();

    //Calling foo method
    foo.testLog4j();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.debug("This is a debug message");
    logger.info("This is an info message");
    logger.warn("This is a warn message");
    logger.error("This is an error message");
    logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
  }

}
```

And these are the output in console

So, my question is how can I add FooClass in my log4j.properties file. Because I added next to TestMain class like this " fnel.bcp.org.main.TestMain , fnel.bcp.org.main.FooClass" , but not work.

I tried to separate in different logger.rolling.name, but didn't work too.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly your referenced libraries aren't being included when trying to use Log4j? I had the same problem, and you actually have to copy the referenced libraries and put it into the output file.

Comment: This is a Log4j 2 question. Claims that this question already has answers are incorrect: The links to previous answers are for Log4j 1 and *do not apply* to Log4j 2.

Comment: @RemkoPopma: as an 8K user you should know better than to add re-open requests in question titles. Your options are to cast a reopen vote, and/or ping the close voter to see if you can get them to reassess. You _might_ be able to go to a suitable chat room and ask for reopen votes (or same from Close Voters Chat, not sure) as long as you don't do the same for up/downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
logger.rolling.name = fnel.bcp.org.main.TestMain
```

to

```
logger.rolling.name = fnel.bcp.org.main
```

this will cause any class in the fnel.bcp.org.main package to be directed to the RollingFile appender. Alternatively, if you want everything in the file you can just remove your logger definition and change the root logger to be directed to RollingFile instead of STDOUT.

Comment: +10 informative as usual. Please also cast your vote to reopen since this question was incorrectly closed as duplicate.